# ¿Está bien preguntar cosas que no sabemos pero que podemos encontrar fácilmente en SO en inglés?

Tags: discusión

Hoy tuve una duda, bastante básica, que nadie había preguntado todavía en SO en español.

La publiqué, pero después me di cuenta que en SO en inglés ya habían publicado varias respuestas (aunque todavía no encontré una respuesta que satisfaga totalmente mi duda).

¿Se espera de nosotros que escribamos preguntas aquí, dudas que realmente tengamos, aunque podamos encontrar las respuestas con facilidad en SO en inglés? (durante la Beta).

Answer (score 11):

Pues claro que es correcto. Puede haber varias razones para ello:

1. Tu nivel de inglés no te permite sacar partido de las respuestas existentes
2. Como tú mismo dices: existen respuestas pero ninguna de ellas satisface totalmente tu duda (en ese caso, resulta útil que menciones dichas respuestas y el porqué de tu "insatisfacción")
3. Crees que la comunidad de este sitio podría darte mejores respuestas y/o información o recursos adicionales

Lo importante es tener claro que si bien el sitio Stack Overflow original es la inspiración para este sitio, no somos un calco del mismo.

Comment: Konamiman, note que editaste mi pregunta. Gracias! tengo un teclado en inglés y es bastante difícil agregar todos los acentos y demás. Tengo que adivinar donde esta qué. Pero cambiaste una palabra que cambia el significado de mi pregunta. Yo no pregunte si es correcto, quiero saber si se espera que nosotros hagamos eso. Me puedo manejar perfectamente en SO en Ingles, pero quiero ayudar a la comunidad de SO en español. Como crecimiento orgánico, yo realmente tuve esta duda, pero podria encontrar la respuesta en otro sitio. La pregunto igual para enriquecer el sitio?

Comment: Mis disculpas, a veces me paso de entusiasmo editando. :-) De todas formas tal como está ahora ("se espera de nosotros") se entiende mucho mejor que antes ("es esperado").

Comment: Si a veces tanto ingles le quita a uno el castellano!